# Transparent styling to table when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, leaflet

I've created a table with some simple styling elements such as borders, colors, etc. When attempting to print this table, the print preview does not show any of my CSS. I've seen some answers suggesting it's a bootstrap.css issue but after attempting some of the fixes, it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have also made sure that the "background graphics" option is selected in the browser during print preview.

Is there a way to access the code or `css` of the print preview page as opposed to my actual code? Or is there another fix that I'm missing?

If it helps, I'm using `leaflet` and a print plugin, everything looks right except for the table. Thank you for taking the time to read or answer this, I've attached a photo of the table in print preview.

**Screenshot of my table missing styling in print preview.**

[image: Screenshot of my table missing styling in print preview.]

Comment: You'll probably have to specify a print stylesheet. https://www.jotform.com/blog/css-perfect-print-stylesheet-98272/

Comment: ... or the printing options of the browser are filtering images and borders out.

Comment: I have a separate print.css file and have also gone through browser settings to allow background, color, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

to style the printing preview.
I see. print css and main css is difference.
So you style it in other ways.

for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />


body {
  margin: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

/* override styles when printing */
@media print {

  body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity:0.3;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add missing bootstrap classes in your css file with @media print. Example:

```
@media print {
    .table td {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

More about media print:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media